# How do I speed up an optimized CPU-bound process that runs within a parallelized program in Python?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

A Python program of mine uses the `multiprocessing` module to parallelize iterations of a search problem. Besides doing other things, each iteration loops over a CPU-expensive process that is already optimized in Cython. Because this process gets called multiple times while looping, this significantly slows down the total runtime.

What is the recommended way to achieve a speed-up in this case? As the expensive process can't be further CPU-optimized, I've considered parallelizing the loop. However, as the loop lives in an already parallelized (by `multiprocessing`) program, I don't think this would be possible on the same machine.

My research on this has failed to find any best practices or any sort of direction.

Comment: This is not my field of expertise, but did you consider using a GIL-less Python implementation and having the processes spawn threads?

Comment: Did you mean CPython or Cython? There is no magical way to make a program use more resources than actually available. You only way is to use them more efficiently or reconsider the use of other computing resources (only) if the first cannot be done. Are you sure that the computation is really optimal? From my experience, most Python codes are really far from being close the the optimal time. For example: do you use the best algorithms? the best data structure? are the overheads of CPython negligible? does the current code scale well? etc. We need more information to help you.

Comment: @JérômeRichard It's Cython (corrected). For context, the code spends a lot of time on the following method, which is optimized for speed: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/exponential_smoothing/ets.py#L947

Comment: Interesting! The code appear to use the L-BFGS algorithm which should be compute bound. It also uses some Numpy functions (eg. log & sum) which are probably not well optimized for your platform. It is hard to me to see which part is the bottleneck. If you do a minimal reproducible example calling it with context/input matching with your needs (eg. parallel use), then I will try to check if the code can be improved further. I think there is a room for improvement but the code already use Numpy and the Numpy code is quite good. So do not expect a massive improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick way to see if it *might* be possible to optimize your existing code, you might check your machines CPU usage while the code is running.

If all your cores are ~100% then adding more processes etc isn't likely to improve things.

In that case you could

1 - Try further algorithm optimisation (though best bang for the buck is to profile your code first to see where it's slow).  *Though if you've already been using Cython then likely this might have limited returns*

2 - Try a faster machine and/or with more cores

Another approach however (one that I've used) is instead to develop a serverless design, and run your CPU intensive, parallel parts of your algorithm using any of the cloud vendors serverless models.

I've personally used AWS lamda, where we parallelized our code to run with 200+ simultaneous lambda processes, that is roughly equivalent to a 200+ core single machine.

For us, this essentially resulted in a *50-100 times increase in performance* (measured as reduction in total processing time) compared to running on a 8-core server.

You do have to do more work to implement a serverless deployment model, and then wrapper code to manage everything, which isn't trivial.  However the ability to essentially scale infinitely horizontally may potentially make sense for you.

Comment: I agree with the first part but not with the second one: using more resources should be the last thing to do (after checking the algorithm, the method, the needs and the inputs as well as possible bugs) unless they are already freely available. In practice there is no free lunch: using more machines is more expensive, consumes more energy, may add some complexity to run the code, and often add a dependencies to specific providers (eg. AWS/Azure). I have seen many people using very-inefficient parallel codes running on a lot of resources while an optimized sequential code was almost faster.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'd have to agree with you - I've written libraries for scientific code running on supercomputers where you spend most of your time on optimizations, and the seemingly focus nowdays on 'lazy' coding and design wrt optimization wastes so many resources.  Especially when coding nowdays is less about real coding and more about gluing 3rd party 'services' together.  Sure it may be faster to market, but it's slower, more complex, more fragile, more opaque etc etc.

Comment: @laos ...not implying here that you've missed something.  If you've already invested the time to go down the Cython route, then likely you've already done a good job of optimizing at a per-core level.  If you have exhausted optimization on a per-core level, then something like AWS lambda might be a next step.